# Switching between activities through Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have 2 activities which extend a base activity:

`Class BaseActivity extends Activity`
`Class A extends BaseActivity`
`Class B extends BaseActivity`

Now I have a button on **A** which allows the user to go to **B**, and a button on **B** which allows to go back to **A**.

So far, so good.
Now after reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) documentation, which is straightforward enough, I am implementing an additional activity between **BaseActivity** and **A**, **B**. The structure will be:

`Class BaseActivity extends Activity`
`Class MyDrawer extends BaseActivity`
`Class A extends MyDrawer`
`Class B extends MyDrawer`

The activity **MyDrawer** contains the code to use a Navigation Drawer. The problem I have is, I am not able to understand how do I use my Activities instead of Fragments in the Navigation Drawer. I want the users to be able to switch between activities through the drawer. Is this possible? or do I need to rewrite everything using Fragments instead of Activities?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to change to using `Activities` instead of `Fragments`? What functionality can't you use when using `Fragments`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I already have the implementation using **Activities** :). I'm asking if I can add the **navigation drawer** without changing my implementation, or rewrite all **activities** as **fragments**.

Comment: did you got any solution for this scenario.

Comment: No I didn't. I had to convert those activities to fragments.

Comment: I highly suggest rather than trying to find a solution to what you have asked learn the correct way of implementing a navigation drawer with fragments. What you're doing is just completely wrong and don't get used to doing it. And it doesn't take a much of an effort to convert activities to fragments.

Comment: This post provided an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467516/navigation-drawer-to-switch-between-activities

Answer (score 0):

Use intent's to switch between the activities. Refer to 
[Navigation Drawer to switch between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467516/navigation-drawer-to-switch-between-activities)

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
Intent intent = null;
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity_0.class);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity_1.class);
        break;

    ...


    case 4: 
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity_4.class);
        break;

    default : 
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity_0.class); // Activity_0 as default
        break;
}

startActivity(intent);
```

}