# Navigation Drawer to switch between activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have browsed the website for a bit and I can't find an answer to my problem, I am trying to get my Navigation Drawer to switch between activities instead of fragments. I have tried switch statements and all that does is crash the app, I don't know how to get the separate elements of the drawer in order to set them up so that if one is pressed, it will go to this page and if the other is pressed it will go to this page etc etc.

Here's my code,

```
package com.example.ColeraineTown;

imports...

public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // 2. App Icon
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
    );

    // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
    // then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

    }
}
```

}

I have been at this all day, trying to fix it and get it working, but no luck. It took me so long to get the actual drawer working in the first place it would be a shame to see it all gone.

If you guys have the answer to being able to switch between the activities, that would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you have 5 items (from 0 index to 4), each index identifying an Activity of your project. You can create a method `selectItem(int position)`to know what drawer item has been chosen by user.

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_0.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_1.class);
            break;

        ...


        case 4: 
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_4.class);
            break;

        default : 
            intent = new Intent(this, Activity_0.class); // Activity_0 as default
            break;
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Finally, add this method to your `DrawerItemClickListener` :

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

    }
}
```

It's easier than using `Fragment`s, I think !!!

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't figure out how to use the position, but I figured out it had something to do with it :)

Comment: Ok, so you solved the issue ?! if yes do not forget to mark the answer as the `correct`. An upvote will be pleasing too :)

Comment: It works but you do not have the navigation drawer in the activity you started :(