# Want to move to another activity from navigation drawer

Tags: android

i have a map activity. and it has a navigation drawer. but when i click in any of the navigation items i cant go to another activity. i am attaching my code here.there is no errors. When i click any item of the navigation drawer its not moving to another activity.

```
     nv = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv);
            nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.profile:

                            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;
                        case R.id.dona:
                            Intent j = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DonateActivity.class);
                            startActivity(j);
                            break;

                        case R.id.pla:
                            Intent k = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PlantActivity.class);
                            startActivity(k);
                            break;

                        case R.id.not:
                            Intent l = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
                            startActivity(l);
                            break;

                        case R.id.hist:
                            Intent m = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(m);
                            break;

                        case R.id.hel:
                            Intent n = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                            startActivity(n);
                            break;



                    }

                    return false;

                }
            });





 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }






 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (t.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        int id = item.getItemId();



        if (id == R.string.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me error what you got

Comment: Are you sure it's HomeActivity? Try getActivity instead

Comment: There is no error. When I click any item on my navigation drawer i have to move to another activity. ihave added a switch case and an intent in in. but when i click nothing happens

Comment: @Arahasya HomeActivity is my current activity

Comment: @AseelAli your code looks like fine..you have to debug your code, and check all the activities are registered to manifest file. Also check your current Activity i.e. be sure it's HomeActivity

Comment: You are not closing the drawer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467742/10290109

Comment: @RishavSingla yes i do checked. still not working

Comment: @Arahasya I did..still not working

Comment: share your code on github so that i can check it

Comment: @Arahasya I dont know how to share code on github. But I can share the code or the entire project via google drive. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes okay share it

Comment: @Arahasya  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ig85OXSI4lgG7FVie2adT36vhAd8pdZW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully examaning your full code I realized that the .setNavigationItemSelectedListener was not being called. Even if the the drawer was displaying it was at the back of your activity. So you were not actually clicking on it.

So the simple solutuion is :

```
nv.bringToFront();
```

Put this after you initialize nv

Comment: Also click the upward arrow if you find the answer useful

Comment: i need one more help

Comment: Hey
I need a help
I have an activity which contains the map and notificatiin. So when i goes to this activity i want to diaplay an overlay image with 4 imagebuttons in it. Before accessing the map. I will attach the screenshot link from google drive below. Pls do help

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NP9DlHqdjg57SIGPOFBzostxI22PU8E4/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: so what's the problem

Comment: I dont know how to add an image by overlaying it and adding 4 image buttins on it.

Comment: Google it then. Do it yourself first. Stackoverflow is only for problem solving

Answer (score 1):

> you need to `return true`in end of `onNavigationItemSelected`

```
  nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.profile:

                            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            break;

                        /*--your code--*/


                        case R.id.hist:
                            Intent m = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(m);
                            break;

                        case R.id.hel:
                            Intent n = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
                            startActivity(n);
                            break;



                    }

                yourDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                    return true;       //you need to return true here, not false

                }
            });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182564/discussion-on-answer-by-thunder-want-to-move-to-another-activity-from-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- I am using direct on item selected click method like this

  ```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
  int id = item.getItemId();

  if (id == R.id.nav_buildings) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,BuildingsActivity.class));

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_companies) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,CompaniesActivity.class));

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_reports) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,ReportsActivity.class));

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_invoice) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,InvoiceActivity.class));

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_notifications) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,NotificationsActivity.class));

  } else if (id == R.id.nav_ticket) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,TicketActivity.class));

  }
  else if (id == R.id.nav_my_ticket) {
      startActivity(new Intent(SuperAdminHomeActivity.this,TicketsAddActivity.class));
  }

  else if(id==R.id.nav_logout){
      alertDialogue("Do you want to logout?");
  }

  drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  return true;
   }
  ```
- i am not using  drawer click listener.
- this is my drawer layout

[image]

its working fine please try

Comment: you have closed the drawe here right. is this the drawer layout you are closing?

Comment: Still not getting

Answer (score -1):

Make your Navigation View a global variable